# Google Analytics tracking code in external JS File

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I add Google Analytics tracking code to my website.

How do I make an external JS and link that to all of my web pages?

```
(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste the google Analytics code in a file, for example "googleanalytics.js" and include it in the pages you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="googleanalytics.js" ></script>
```

Comment: is there any difference ? adding code on every page or link to a external JS?

Comment: As far as I know there shouldn't be any significant differences. Using a js file generates one HTTP GET more than embed the javascript in the HTML, but if performance is not a critical issue in your website you shouldn't worry about it.